# How to show object's objects like in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

In `ipython` I can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to view an object's objects:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.
Display all 590 possibilities? (y or n)
np.ALLOW_THREADS              np.bartlett                   np.errstate                   np.isclose                    np.nested_iters               np.seterrcall
np.BUFSIZE                    np.base_repr                  np.euler_gamma                np.iscomplex                  np.newaxis                    np.seterrobj
np.CLIP                       np.bench                      np.exp                        np.iscomplexobj               np.newbuffer                  np.setxor1d
np.ComplexWarning             np.binary_repr                np.exp2                       np.isfinite                   np.nextafter                  np.shape
np.DataSource                 np.bincount                   np.expand_dims                np.isfortran                  np.nonzero                    np.shares_memory
....
```

Is there a programmatic way to do this outside of `ipython`? Could I print these objects out in a regular Python script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`dir(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#dir) command can be used to obtain a list of the attributes an object holds. For instance:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dir(np)
['ALLOW_THREADS', 'BUFSIZE', 'CLIP', 'ComplexWarning', 'DataSource', 'ERR_CALL', 'ERR_DEFAULT', 'ERR_IGNORE', 'ERR_LOG', 'ERR_PRINT', 'ERR_RAISE', 'ERR_WARN', 'FLOATING_POINT_SUPPORT', 'FPE_DIVIDEBYZERO', 'FPE_INVALID', 'FPE_OVERFLOW', 'FPE_UNDERFLOW',..., 'var', 'vdot', 'vectorize', 'version', 'void', 'void0', 'vsplit', 'vstack', 'warnings', 'where', 'who', 'zeros', 'zeros_like']
```

(the output is cutted to make it easier to fetch and format it).

It returns a list of strings that show what is in an object. Note that this function can also be used to **program in Python** as well: you could for instance iterate over it, filter for a certain pattern and copy these attributes to another object. For instance you could write a `copy_fields` function:

```
def copy_fields(frm,to):
    for attr in dir(frm):
        setattr(to,atr,getattr(frm,atr))
```

Here [`getattr(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#setattr) are function that given an object (`frm` and `to`) and the name of an attribute (`attr`) respectively get and set that attribute.

I'm quite confident that this is what happens (more or less) behind the curtains of `ipython` (although probably ipython also aims to derive the type such that it can write a parenthesis (`(`) for functions, etc.

Finally mind that `dir(..)` can't always report all attributes (since sometimes attributes can be processed by functions resulting in the fact that an object has "virtually" an infinite amount of attributes; that is for instance the case for objects in `BeautifulSoup` where, if the attribute is not a standardized one, BeautifulSoup sees it as a query). Behind the curtains `dir(..)` works as follows:

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called
>   and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that
>   implement a custom `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` function to
>   customize the way `dir()` reports their attributes.
>
> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best
>   to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not
>   necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a
>   custom `__getattr__()`.

[(source)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 3):

The tab view show above will require formatting which I will not do here, but getting the attributes of an object can be done with the `dir(MyObject)` built in function. This will return a list of all attributes.